# $\lim_{x\to\pi/2} \cos x\cdot\cos(\tan x)$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I wanted to solve the problem without L'Hopital's rule and was having problems in how to show that the limit does not exist.

Any pointers on how I could approach the problem would be super helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $|\cos (tanx ) | \leq 1$ so the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Kavi Rama Murthy's comment,
using [squeeze theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), since the inequality
$$ 0 \le |\cos x \cos(\tan x) | \le | \cos x|$$ holds, we must have desired limit to be equal to 0.